# Ignore device that has malfunctioned

Tags: windows, hardware-failure

Using Windows 7, I am getting this message

> USB Device Not Recognized
>   One of the USB devices attached to this computer has
>   malfunctioned, and Windows does not recognize it.

However I do not have any USB devices plugged in. I went to Device Manager and it looks like its actually the Fingerprint Reader that has failed. I do not need this device and am happy to ignore the message, but it pops up every minute and is annoying.

In Device Manager, I have tried disabling it, uninstalling it, and even removing the drivers.

Does Windows have a way to simply disable these messages?

[image: usb]

Comment: It may be possible to disable the device in the BIOS settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've tried disabling it, that suggests that it isn't actually the fingerprint device itself. I wonder if it is actually the USB device "hub" that the fingerprint reader is attached to?

My fingerprint reader is attached to one of the internal host controllers. If you switch to "View\Devices By Connection", you can hunt it down. Then perhaps try disabling the hub it is attached to. If that isn't enough, try working up the tree.

Comment: While you're at it, see if disconnecting the FP Reader is an option. Then you might be able to save the USB hub that might host other devices like dvd-roms (i assume this is a laptop?). Unplugging would be better than cutting... :-)